# How do I validate if a user has already registered?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First and foremost, thanks to everyone taking time to read through this post. Many, many thanks in advance.

I'm currently building a small registration system for classes. I'm stopping users from registering twice to the same event through the model with "validates :user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :occurrence_id}" in my Registration controller. I want to extend this to my views by greying out a "register" button.

I'm thinking that the best way is by writing a method in the occurrence model that goes something like this:

```
def already_registered?(user)
  if user.id == self.registrations.find()
    false
  else
    true
  end
end
```

Now I know for sure that this doesn't work. How can I search if one occurrence has been has not been register by the current user?

models/registration.rb

```
class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :occurrence

 attr_accessible :occurrence_id, :registration_date, :user_id, :occurrence, :user

 validates :user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :occurrence_id}

end
```

models/occurrence.rb

```
class Occurrence < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :location
  has_many :registrations
  has_many :users, :through => :registrations

  validates :price, :presence => true

  attr_accessible :course_id, :datetime_end, :datetime_start, :location_id, :price, :teacher_id, :class_size

  def remaining_seats
    self.class_size - self.registrations.count
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I really understand your question, but try with

```
def already_registered?(ocurrence)
  self.registrations.where(:ocurrence => ocurrence).any?
end
```

and you call it with

```
current_user.already_registered?(current_ocurrence)
```

Comment: My first impression was to call it from the occurrence model instead of the user. Why did you take this approach?

Comment: I used this code thanks to your explanation!
    def already_registered?(user)
    Registration.where(:user_id => user, :occurrence_id => self).any?
  end

Comment: It just depend on you. One way it would mean "hey, user, are you registered on this ocurrence?" and the other way it would men "hey, ocurrence(?), is this user registered on you?", for me it's clearer the user.already_registered? way since it's more "real" (you would ask a person if he has registered)

Comment: Thanks for your imput! It does make a lot of sense!